# Google Script variable undefined

Tags: javascript

I am creating a script in code.gs and would like to retrieve variables in an interface on an HTML page.

I can not retrieve a variable from a function in code.js on the html page

Code.gs :

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function test(){
 var test="hello";
return test;
}
```

Index.html :

```
google.script.run.test();

document.writeln(test);
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, for example, how about this modification of "Index.html"? `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(test => document.writeln(test)).test();` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tanaike !

Now I'm trying to implement values ​​from an array of code.gs in the html page

**CODE.GS :**

```
function temperature2(){
var valueTemp = new Array([],[],[]);

valueTemp[0][1] = "6"
valueTemp[0][2] = "7"
valueTemp[0][3] = "8"

valueTemp[1][1] = "32"
valueTemp[1][2] = "45"
valueTemp[1][3] = "41"


  return valueTemp;
}
```

**INDEX.html :**

```
data: [ 
[google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[0][1]).temperature2,
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[1][1]).temperature2()],
 [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[0][2]).temperature2, 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[1][2]).temperature2()], 
[google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[0][3]).temperature2, 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(valueTemp[1][3]).temperature2()], 
........  ]
```

I modify the code to shorten it, so that it is more readable